# Zero-byte Application being installed from pkgbuild generated .pkg installer

Tags: macos, shell, pkgbuild, pkg-file

this is the shell script that I use to generate the `.pkg` installer.

```
#!/bin/bash

APP_PATH=$1
DSYM_PATH=$2
PKG_PATH=$3
IDENTIFIER=$4
VERSION=$5
TARGET_DIR=$(dirname "$APP_PATH")/temp

echo "Deleting old Pkg File."
rm -rf $PKG_PATH
rm -rf $TARGET_DIR
mkdir $TARGET_DIR
echo "Done."

echo "Copying APP \"$APP_PATH\" and dSYM \"$DSYM_PATH \" to temp folder."

cp -a $APP_PATH $TARGET_DIR
cp -a $DSYM_PATH $TARGET_DIR

echo "Done."


echo "Generating .Pkg file with dSYM folder"

/usr/bin/pkgbuild \
  --root "$TARGET_DIR" \
  --install-location "/Applications" \
  --identifier "$IDENTIFIER" \
  --version "$VERSION" \
  "$PKG_PATH"

echo "Done Generating \"$APP_PATH\" with dSYM folder"
```

This `.pkg` is installed to `/Applications` folder but it's `zero byte` in size.

I've tried to change the permission of the files but it's no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue, I had to change the permissions for files.

I've added the following line in the script.

`chmod -R 755 $TARGET_DIR`

The file with wrong permission will result a `zero-bytes` installation.

```
#!/bin/bash

APP_PATH=$1
DSYM_PATH=$2
PKG_PATH=$3
IDENTIFIER=$4
VERSION=$5
TARGET_DIR=$(dirname "$APP_PATH")/temp

echo "Deleting old Pkg File."
rm -rf $PKG_PATH
rm -rf $TARGET_DIR
mkdir $TARGET_DIR
echo "Done."

echo "Copying APP \"$APP_PATH\" and dSYM \"$DSYM_PATH \" to temp folder."

cp -a $APP_PATH $TARGET_DIR
cp -a $DSYM_PATH $TARGET_DIR

echo "Done."

chmod -R 755 $TARGET_DIR

echo "Generating .Pkg file with dSYM folder"

/usr/bin/pkgbuild \
  --root "$TARGET_DIR" \
  --install-location "/Applications" \
  --identifier "$IDENTIFIER" \
  --version "$VERSION" \
  "$PKG_PATH"

echo "Done Generating \"$APP_PATH\" with dSYM folder"
```